# How To Make Query report like this?

Tags: php, sql

I just want make query report like this but always fail when going to angsuran_ke =3 can't change value query saldo total pinjaman please help me

IMAGE REPORT
[image: IMAGE REPORT]

IMAGE CODE
[image: IMAGE CODE]

```
SELECT tb_nasabah.id_nasabah
     , tb_nasabah.nama
     , tb_angsuran.angsuran_ke
     , tb_angsuran.tgl_angsur
     , if(tb_angsuran.angsuran_ke > 1 && angsuran_ke <= 10,
          (tb_pinjaman.besar_pinjaman_sekarang - tb_angsuran.besar_angsuran), besar_pinjaman_sekarang) as total
     , tb_angsuran.besar_angsuran,besar_pinjaman_sekarang
FROM tb_nasabah,
     tb_pinjaman,
     tb_angsuran
where tb_nasabah.id_nasabah = tb_pinjaman.id_anggota
  and tb_nasabah.id_nasabah = tb_angsuran.id_nasabah
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can we have some sample data?

Comment: when in angsuran ke 3 fields in total data do not change and should change from a reduction besar_pinjaman_sekarang - besar angsuran

Comment: Can we have some sample data please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wUGBdW2c

Comment: No, I mean can we get the results of this query: SELECT * FROM tb_nasabah WHERE angsuran_ke = 3 LIMIT 10;